# ColumnTransformer , remainder - passthrough gives me Error

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, column-tansformer

I have a small dataset, like this

```
_d=pd.DataFrame([
    [1,2.0,'a','mango','2017-07-07',1],
        [2,2.55,'b','apple','2017-08-07',0],
        [3,5.7,np.nan,'bannan',np.nan,1],
        [4,np.nan,'d','grpaes','2017-09-07',1],
        [5,5.7,'e','pineapple','2017-10-07',0],
        [6,8.3,np.nan,'orange','2017-01-07',0],
      [5,5.7,'e',np.nan,'2017-10-07',1],
        [6,np.nan,'f',np.nan,np.nan,0],
        [7,6.8,'g','pomegranate','2017-02-07',1],
        [np.nan,55.5,'h','water melon','2017-03-07',0],
        [9,6.8,'i','mango',np.nan,1],
        [10,3.5,np.nan,'orange','2017-06-07',1],
        [11,2.78,'k','pomegranate','2017-09-07',0] 
] ,columns=['ind','score','grade','group','da','target']      
)
```

[image]

To handle NaN values and encode the category features, I used this code

```
y=_d['target']
x=_d.drop(['target'],axis=1)

int_columns=_d.select_dtypes(['float64','int64']).columns
obj_columns=_d.select_dtypes(['object','category']).columns


int_pipeline=Pipeline([
    ('impute_values',SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')),
    ('scaling',StandardScaler())
])
cat_pipeline=Pipeline([
    ('cat_impute',SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='missing')),
    ('encoding',OneHotEncoder(drop='first'))
])


column_trans=ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
   ('int_p',int_pipeline,['ind', 'score']),
     ('cat_p',cat_pipeline,['grade', 'group'])
],remainder='passthrough')

mdl_pipeline=Pipeline([
    ('value_transform',column_trans)
])
transformed_data=mdl_pipeline.fit_transform(x,y)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-07-07'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [253], in <cell line: 27>()
> 18 column_trans=ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
> 19    ('int_p',int_pipeline,['ind', 'score']),
> 20      ('cat_p',cat_pipeline,['grade', 'group'])
> 21 ],remainder='passthrough')
> 23 mdl_pipeline=Pipeline([
> 24     ('value_transform',column_trans)
> 25 #     ,('mdl',LogisticRegression())
> 26 ])
> ---> 27 transformed_data=mdl_pipeline.fit_transform(x,y)
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:434, in
> Pipeline.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
> 432 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
> 433 if hasattr(last_step, "fit_transform"):
> --> 434     return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
> 435 else:
> 436     return last_step.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step).transform(Xt)
>
> File
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py:699,
> in ColumnTransformer.fit_transform(self, X, y)
> 696 self._validate_output(Xs)
> 697 self._record_output_indices(Xs)
> --> 699 return self._hstack(list(Xs))
>
> File
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py:783,
> in ColumnTransformer._hstack(self, Xs)
> 778         converted_Xs = [
> 779             check_array(X, accept_sparse=True, force_all_finite=False)
> 780             for X in Xs
> 781         ]
> 782     except ValueError as e:
> --> 783         raise ValueError(
> 784             "For a sparse output, all columns should "
> 785             "be a numeric or convertible to a numeric."
> 786         ) from e
> 788     return sparse.hstack(converted_Xs).tocsr()
> 789 else:
>
> ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or
> convertible to a numeric.

The value error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-07-07'

doesnt make any sense, as I have set remainder='passthrough', In the columnTransformer, Why is my code not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `sparse_threshold=0` of  your `ColumnTransformer`. Otherwise, according to [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

> If the output of the different transformers contains sparse matrices, these will be stacked as a sparse matrix if the overall density is lower than this value. Use sparse_threshold=0 to always return dense. When the transformed output consists of all dense data, the stacked result will be dense, and this keyword will be ignored.

So it's trying to convert results of `OneHotEncoder` to sprase matrix but it can't since sparse matrices require numerical values (hence attempt to convert to something numerical)

Comment: it worked, when i made the changes but could you explain me why am i getting this error